# Make div stay active in any page on a website

Tags: javascript, css, html

Is it possible to have a  stay on the page regardless of where the users goes to within the website?

Example: https://youtu.be/T3f-MPPH4Co

Answer (score 1, accepted):

content can be done by positioning within a specific item.

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application